# В с++ getline дает нечто странное

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, getline

Получаю поток std::istream, считываю строку методом getline(stream, line).

```
std::getline(stream,l);
    std::vector<std::string> line=split(l,":");
    //query="INSERT INTO Project(Name) VALUES ("+line[1]+";";
    query=(boost::format("INSERT INTO Project(Name) VALUES (%s);")% trim(line[1])).str();
    std::cout<<query<<std::endl;
```

Что в первом (закомментировано) случае, что во втором (с boost) в результате получаю ");"

Comment: В вашем вопросе спрятано два. Ответ на первый вопрос - добавьте в конец std::flush()

Comment: Если не использовать переход на следующую строку, то ничего не будет выведено. При конкатенации строк это нечто все ломает

Comment: Правильно, потому что библиотека C++ и операционка буферизуют вывод. Чтобы вывелось, нужно из пнуть - вызвать flush()

Comment: а как пнуть при конкатенации? Так понимаю, я уже получил строку, она разбилась по разделителю, но с последним куском не все так просто. Описание магии добавил

Comment: Нельзя собирать запрос конкатенацией. Это дыра в приложении размером с РБМК-1000! Называется SQL-Injection. Используйте Prepared Statements! С какой СУБД вы работаете?

Comment: Вопрос заключается не в этом.

Comment: Про какую еще "конкатенацию " идет речь? Где в `std::cout<<line;` конкатенация???

Comment: конкатенация происходит в query=...("+line[1]+";" или та же строка собирается при помощи boost::format

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy

Вот это почитайте

Comment: @AnT,  вопрос оформлен  неудачно, поэтому возник ваш вопрос

Comment: Вопрос изменен, надеюсь, так понятнее.